# Can't connect to local host form android emulator

Tags: android, django, localhost, httprequest

So I have a django server running on my local machine that I want to connect to through an android app that I am running in the emulator. Everything works fine when I type this into the web browser (i get the json object I am expecting back). But my android code is not working.

```
    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(new URI("http://10.0.2.2:8080/getUserInfo/" + username + "/"));

        //next line throws exception
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();  
        if (resEntity != null) {  
             Log.i("GET RESPONSE",EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
             String jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
             return jsonToAccount(jsonString);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
```

I have tried subbing in `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` for `10.0.2.2` and I have also tried port 8000 instead of 8080, can anybody see the problem?

Here is the stack trace: (you can read it if you open it in a new tab)

[image]

Comment: No. But you can. Please post the stack trace :)

Comment: Never set up a server on the pc and used it to test apps in the emulator, but: Wouldn't `127.0.0.1` and so on reference to the phone/emulator as the local host in this case, as opposed to the host computer you are trying to reach?

Comment: what do you type in the web browser (exactly)?

Comment: In my case i used 192.168.1.X

Comment: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/getUserInfo/willyb/` or `http://localhost:8000/getUserInfo/willyb/` Both work, and I have tried both in that code

Comment: does anyone know if @alextsc is right?

Comment: ok if 8000 is your port, why do you try 8080? Anyway - it's clearly a permission problem, can you post your httpd.conf?

Comment: don't think I have one of those... maybe thats the problem?

Comment: @alextsc is not right...10.0.2.2 definitely works..tried it. It refers to your computer on which the emulator is running.

Comment: @Urban Ok, thanks for testing. Was just the first thing that came to my head.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

put

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

in your android-manifest